# java.lang.IllegalStateException:JSON OBJECT and JSON ARRAY when parsing Json using GSON

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit2

Server JSON Data display in activity using Retrofit. JSON data convert through gson.

Gives Error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

JSON Format :

```
{"success":1,"company":[{"Cmp_Id":"1","Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA"}]}
```

Code:

```
class Company {

  //@SerializedName("Cmp_Id")
  var Cmp_Id : Int = 0

  //@SerializedName("success")
  //val success : String = ""

  //@SerializedName("Cmp_Name")
  var Cmp_Name : String? = ""

  //@SerializedName("GSTIN")
  var GSTIN : String? = ""
}


class CompanyList {
  val success : String = ""

  lateinit var company : ArrayList<Company>
}


interface APIInterface { 
  @GET("Company.php")
  fun getCompanyData() : Observable<List<CompanyList>>
}


object APIClient {

  val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/"
  var retrofit:Retrofit? = null
  val apIClient:Retrofit?
    get() {
        if (retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit =  Retrofit.Builder().
                    baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build()
        }
        return retrofit
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
private fun fetchData(){
   /* compositeDisposable.add(api.getCompanyData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { companyList-> displayData(companyList)
            }
    )*/

    val retrofit = APIClient.apIClient
    if (retrofit != null) {
        api = retrofit.create(APIInterface::class.java)
    }

    api.getCompanyData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ companyAdapter.setCompany(it.component1().company)
            },{

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retrofit interface:

```
interface APIInterface {
  @GET("Company.php")
  fun getCompanyData() : Observable<List<CompanyList>>
}
```

Hints retrofit that you expect a list of `CompanyList`. However, the json you receive is a single `CompanyList`. This is what the gson error your getting tells you - Expected to begin with an array but it was an object.

Changing the retrofit interface to:

```
interface APIInterface {
  @GET("Company.php")
  fun getCompanyData() : Observable<CompanyList>
}
```

will hint retrofit that you expect a single object of type `CompanyList` and this should work for the json you've posted.